# How to connect with OpenFire(xmpp) using RESTAPI plugin And PHP

Tags: php, xmpp, openfire

I am using OpenFire to manage my xmpp server I want to add new users using a PHP, So I have installed RESETAPI Plugin to OpenFire to administrate with http request. I am using [gidkom](https://github.com/gidkom/php-openfire-restapi) Project also. But getting a error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in C:\wamp\www\IM\registration.php on line 12
```

My code for registration.php is:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST["User_Name"]) && isset($_POST["Name"]) )
{
$User_ID = $_POST["User_Name"];
$User_Name = $_POST["Name"];
$User_Email = $_POST["Email"];
include "Gidkom/OpenFireRestApi/OpenFireRestApi.php";
// Create the OpenfireUserservice object
$api = new Gidkom\OpenFireRestApi

// Set the required config parameters
$api->secret = "my keys";
$api->host = "domain.my.org";
$api->port = "9090";  // default 9090

// Optional parameters (showing default values)

$api->useSSL = false;
$api->plugin = "/plugins/restapi/v1";  // plugin 

// Add a new user to OpenFire and add to a group
$result = $api->addUser($User_ID, 'Password', $User_Name, $User_Email, array('welcome'));

// Check result if command is succesful
if($result['status']) {
    // Display result, and check if it's an error or correct response
    echo 'Success: ';
    echo $result['message'];
} else {
    // Something went wrong, probably connection issues
    echo 'Error: ';
    echo $result['message'];
}






//Add to roster
$api->addToRoster('Administrator', 'admin');

}
else
{
echo 'Error: Something went wrong..... <a href="registration.html">please go back</a> ';

}
```

I want the page to add a new new user in the openfire and add admin to his roster.
Thanks !!!!

Comment: Should it be not $api = new Gidkom\OpenFireRestApi\OpenFireRestApi
instead of $api = new Gidkom\OpenFireRestApi

Comment: when I follow your instructions I got this error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in C:\wamp\www\IM\Gidkom\OpenFireRestApi\OpenFireRestApi.php on line 43
line 43 is :$headers += ['Content-Type'=>'application/json'];

Comment: the error is as a result of the php version you are using

Comment: Hi@ChiragSukhala by printing $result = $api->addUser("User_ID", "Password", "User_Name", "User_Email");
print_r($result);die; i am gettingArray ( [status] => 1 [message] => GuzzleHttp\Stream\Stream Object ( [stream:GuzzleHttp\Stream\Stream:private] => Resource id #8 [size:GuzzleHttp\Stream\Stream:private] => [seekable:GuzzleHttp\Stream\Stream:private] => 1 [readable:GuzzleHttp\Stream\Stream:private] => 1 [writable:GuzzleHttp\Stream\Stream:private] => 1 [uri:GuzzleHttp\Stream\Stream:private] => php://temp [customMetadata:GuzzleHttp\Stream\Stream:private] => Array ( ) ) )
Please Help!

Comment: @ShashankShah in my case errors were due to wrong PHP version, make sure you are using the latest PHP version and retry. Let me know if it works :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The errors were caused because of an outdated version of PHP, YPdating PHP to latest version fixed it...

Answer (score 1):

Semicolon is missing.

`$api = new Gidkom\OpenFireRestApi\OpenFireRestApi;`

Answer (score 0):

prerequirements: must to have composer.exe installed on your machine

from cmd.exe
go to your web root server(htdocs) then 
go into your directory which contain the rest api sources

then from this cmd.exe(or create one batch)

c:/..../....> composer install

Remark: -this commnad(composer install)  must to have in same directory the composer.json
        -this command(composer install) will create one subdirectory "vendor" named

now into your index.php must insert on top, the following line:

```
<?php
include "vendor/autoload.php";
....
and continue your actual program
and is trully must to end the lines with ;
...
?
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/gnello/php-openfire-restapi

Easy Php REST API Client for the Openfire REST API Plugin which provides the ability to manage Openfire instance by sending an REST/HTTP request to the server

Please read documentation for further information on using this application.

**Installation**

```
composer require gnello/php-openfire-restapi
```

**Authentication**
There are two ways to authenticate:

**Basic HTTP Authentication**

```
$authenticationToken = new \Gnello\OpenFireRestAPI\AuthenticationToken('your_user', 'your_password');
```

**Shared secret key**

```
$authenticationToken = new \Gnello\OpenFireRestAPI\AuthenticationToken('your_secret_key');
```

**Start**

```
$api = new \Gnello\OpenFireRestAPI\API('your_host', 9090, $authenticationToken);
```

**Users**

```
//Add a new user
$properties = array('key1' => 'value1', 'key2' => 'value2');
$result = $api->Users()->createUser('Username', 'Password', 'Full Name', 'email@domain.com', $properties);

//Delete a user
$result = $api->Users()->deleteUser('Username');

//Ban a user
$result = $api->Users()->lockoutUser('Username');

//Unban a user
$result = $api->Users()->unlockUser('Username');
```

**Open Link Fore more.**